# Aligning Div with Sub Divs content Vertically Aligned Center

Tags: css, css-float

So I have a div which looks like

```
<div id="socialMediaBarHomepage">
<div id="homepageNewsLink">
    <img src="" alt="" class="mr_10"/>
    <a href=""></a>
</div>
<div id="socialMediaHeaderBar" class="fl_right">
    <div id="headerMediaStayConnected" class="fl_left mr_5">
    A bit of Text
    </div>
    <div id="headerMediaIcons" class="fl_left">
    Image Image Image
    </div>
<div>
```

So I have 1 Main div, with 2 sub divs.

1 Floating Left and 1 Floating right. Its basically a bar for my homepage.

On the left I display an icon and a newslink

On the right I display a  label and social media icons.

What I am trying to do is simply vertically align middle everything in this bar, but can't even get close. Any ideas on how to get this done ?

CSS

```
   #homepageNewsLink a, #homepageNewsLink img { float: left; }
```

#headerMediaIcons ul { margin: 0px;}
   #socialMediaBarHomepage { display: table; }
   #homepageNewsLink     { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
   #socialMediaHeaderBar   { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vertical-align CSS property applies only to TD tag and if I remember well some inline objects alignment (like images).
What you can try is to set explicit height of parent div and use on sub-divs margin-top and margin-bottom with value auto
You can also use display:table-cell on parent div and stick to vertical-align.

Comment: Tried that but no joy    #socialMediaBarHomepage { height: 30px;}
   #homepageNewsLink       { margin-top: auto;margin-bottom: auto;}
   #socialMediaHeaderBar   { margin-top: auto;margin-bottom: auto; } The Children div's dont move at all

Comment: Try to set position:relative on your divs or even better avoid floats and use position:absolute or display:inline-block.
Here you go with [some examples of vertical centering with CSS](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/).